# Various data types return in a method without creating an object

Tags: java

I was wondering how i can return these variables(mixed data types) without using an object in the getBasicInfo method. The idea is to print these variables and then print other variables in subclasses through the method getDetails and finally combine both methods in the toString().

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public abstract class Item
{
    protected String name="Kostas";
    protected double price=3.4;
    protected String description="fgadafgd";
    protected int stock=5;
    protected int id=5;

    public String getBasicInfo()
    {
        //code that i need 
    }

    public abstract String getDetails();


    public  String toString()//this is wrong i will fix it later
    {
        return getBasicInfo();
    }


}
```

Comment: That's not possible, since `name` and `description` are already objects.

Comment: I'm wondering if what you are doing makes any sense at all. Hard coded property values

Comment: `getBasicInfo()` is declared as returning a String so it will return a String. Do you want a different return type or are you just asking how you can represent your variables in a Single String? (The answer to that is: However you want to represent them as a String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only expect to extend your class via `getDetails` then `getBasicInfo` could be private or final.

```
public abstract class Item {
    protected String name = "Kostas";
    protected double price = 3.4;
    protected String description = "fgadafgd";
    protected int stock = 5;
    protected int id = 5;

    public final String getBasicInfo() {
        return "name=" + name + "\n" +
                "price=" + price + "\n" +
                "description=" + description + "\n" +
                "stock=" + stock + "\n" +
                "id=" + id + "\n" +
                "name=" + name;
    }

    public abstract String getDetails();

    public String toString()// this is wrong i will fix it later
    {
        return getBasicInfo() + "\n" +
                getDetails();
    }

    public static class MyCustomItem extends Item {

        private String myCustomField = "my custom field value";


        @Override
        public String getDetails() {
            return "myCustomField=" + myCustomField;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MyCustomItem().toString());
    }

}
```